# iOS Crash Follower

Tags: ios, crash, callstack

Is that possible to complete a function(iOS Crash Follower) in the code for finding crash address or grasping the last called function in the callstack when app crashed?

With this function,we can easily to find out where the app crashed and then show crash information on the console, or maybe it can collect crash information before it feedback to us when mobile-net works.

Is anybody knows?

Comment: you can try testflight https://testflightapp.com, flurry http://www.thomashajcak.com/solutions-for-crash-reporting-flurry/ analytics

Comment: you may want to use PLCrashReporter http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/

Comment: http://crittercism.com is pretty cool too

Comment: [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

And give [BugHD](http://bughd.com) a try, iOS OSX & Android all supports, with very detail crash report.